# Shows "no route matches" for delete link rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, action

I am new to ruby with rails 4. The error is coming in the link to delete action.the error is :

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Subjects#index No route
>   matches {:action=>"delete", :controller=>"subjects", :id=>1}

I think the problem is in routing. 
My code for list.html.erb is:

```
<div class="subject list">
    <h2>Subjects</h2>
    <%= link_to("Add New Subject", {:action => 'new'}, :class => 'action new') %>
    <table class="listing" summary="Subject list">
        <tr>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Visible</th>
            <th>Pages</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <% @subjects.each do |subject| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= subject.position %></td>
            <td><%= subject.name %></td>
            <td class="center"><%= subject.visible ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
            <td class="center"><%= subject.pages.size %></td>
            <td class="actions">
                <%= link_to("Show",{:action => 'show', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action show') %>
                <%= link_to("Edit",{:action => 'edit', :id => subject.id}, :class => 'action edit') %>
            <!--error is showing in this line-->    <%= link_to("Delete",{:action => 'delete', :id => subject.id}) %> 

            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
</div>
```

code for route is -

```
resources :subjects
```

All the actions for list, show, edit, update is working except delete and destroy because of my immature routing.
Suggestions will be helpful.

---

i have changed the routes file:

```
 get 'subjects/index'
  get 'subjects/list'
  get 'subjects/new'
  get 'subjects/edit'
  get 'subjects/delete'
  get 'subjects/destroy'
  resources :subjects do
    member do
      get 'show', to: 'show#id'
    end
  end
```

now if I manually call the delete through URL like this

http://localhost:3000/subjects/delete?id=8

then the template is loading .

now if I manually call  the destroy through URL like

http://localhost:3000/subjects/destroy?id=8

even then the data is destroyed from the database

but the link in my list.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', subject, method: :delete %>
```

is calling the show action resulting in this url

```
http://localhost:3000/subjects/1/show
 and the error occurs :


No route matches [DELETE] "/subjects/1/show"

Rails.root: D:/ruby/sam_app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url          
subjects_index_path GET /subjects/index(.:format)   subjects#index
subjects_list_path  GET /subjects/list(.:format)    subjects#list
subjects_new_path   GET /subjects/new(.:format) subjects#new
subjects_edit_path  GET /subjects/edit(.:format)    subjects#edit
subjects_delete_path    GET /subjects/delete(.:format)  subjects#delete
subjects_destroy_path   GET /subjects/destroy(.:format) subjects#destroy
subject_path    GET /subjects/:id/show(.:format)    show#id
subjects_path   GET /subjects(.:format) subjects#index
POST    /subjects(.:format) subjects#create
new_subject_path    GET /subjects/new(.:format) subjects#new
edit_subject_path   GET /subjects/:id/edit(.:format)    subjects#edit
GET /subjects/:id(.:format) subjects#show
PATCH   /subjects/:id(.:format) subjects#update
PUT /subjects/:id(.:format) subjects#update
DELETE  /subjects/:id(.:format) subjects#destroy
```

and same goes for the destroy button present in delete.html.erb

and now I am stuck .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is old but has no chosen answer yet, so I'll give my 2 cents.

This:

```
get 'subjects/index'
get 'subjects/list'
get 'subjects/new'
get 'subjects/edit'
get 'subjects/delete'
get 'subjects/destroy'
resources :subjects do
  member do
    get 'show', to: 'show#id'
  end
end
```

will work with a `GET request` (if you type it on the address bar on your browser) because rails routes has a "first appearance priority", as shown on your log **Routes match in priority from top to bottom**, which means you are creating a `GET destroy` route and `DELETE destroy` created by `resources :subjects` is ignored.

I recommend you to get rid of those `get 'subjects/*'` and use the following code as your delete button:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', subject_path(subject), method: :delete %>
```

and use the `destroy` method on your controller to do your action.

Answer (score 3):

always for reference..copy routes in local file..using

`rake routes >> paths.txt` and then you can refer it anytime..which will look like this

```
                        dashboard_index GET    /dashboard(.:format)                                         dashboard#index
                                        POST   /dashboard(.:format)                                         dashboard#create
                          new_dashboard GET    /dashboard/new(.:format)                                     dashboard#new
                         edit_dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id/edit(.:format)                                dashboard#edit
                              dashboard GET    /dashboard/:id(.:format)                                     dashboard#show
                                        PUT    /dashboard/:id(.:format)                                     dashboard#update
                                        DELETE /dashboard/:id(.:format)                                     dashboard#destroy
```

So as you can see clearly **what method needs which http verbs to work**...
for example my delete action will work only if my method call is of type `delete` as @Marek Lipka said....

Comment: Thats is unnecessary copying that - just go to /x e.g.

[http://localhost:3000/x](http://localhost:3000/x)

Answer (score 2):

The path to `destroy` action is the same as to `show` action (if you use `resources`, of course). The only thing that differs is HTTP method, which is `GET` for `show` and `DELETE` for destroy. So your link should look as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", subject, method: :delete %>
```

Also, you should not have redundant routes for various actions in `subjects` controller, like `get 'subjects/index'` and you shouldn't define member `show` action, like you're trying to do (it doesn't make any sense). Instead, in your routes, you should only have:

```
resources :subjects
```

It's possible that some of your links stop working after this modification, you have to fix them so they use correct routes.

Comment: `bundle exec rake routes` would make your life way easier if you ask me!

Comment: i have changed my link_to statement @marek and now i am getting this error                                                                                                              Routing Error
No route matches [DELETE] "/subjects/1/show"

Rails.root: D:/ruby/sam_app

Comment: everytime it is executing the action "show" instead of "delete"

Comment: @Samvedna are you sure that your link looks exactly as I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

users

GET             /users(.:format)        users#index

POST                /users(.:format)        users#create

new_user GET        /users/new(.:format)        users#new

edit_user GET           /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit

user GET            /users/:id(.:format)        users#show

PATCH           /users/:id(.:format)        users#update

PUT             /users/:id(.:format)        users#update

DELETE          /users/:id(.:format)        users#destroy

You can delete directly by

```
<%= link_to("Delete", user, method: :delete)%>
```

where user include id by default and it will delete your users directly

if you want to execute the delete method first, and from there to execute the destroy method than you need to add the following route in your route file but it should be at the last or default route for your app.

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

Comment: This actually is NOT recommended at all. Matching everything with `match ':controller(/:action(/:id)), :via => [:get, :post]` is a major SECURITY FLAW. It is recommended to explicitly declare each controller, action and method you want it to be accessible instead.